# Set android suffix to EditText using custom class by extending EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I created edit text with prefix with the help of [this example](http://mdev-android.blogspot.com/2014/05/not-editable-prefix-in-edittext.html).

Same way I tried to achieve suffix to edit text. I have successfully added suffix to the right side of my cursor.But it's not display at the very end of the Edit text. when I type on it, the typed text overlay on suffix. I know there are other way of achieving this but I'm trying to pull this off.Please help.

Basically I need to fulfill these functionalities.

- Suffix should display at the end of the edit text.
- Suffix should not be overlay from the text typed by the user.

here's my code.

```
public class SuffixEditText extends EditText {

private String mSuffix = "Suffix";
private Rect mSuffixRect = new Rect();

public SuffixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    getPaint().getTextBounds(mSuffix, 0, mSuffix.length(), mSuffixRect);
    mSuffixRect.left += getPaint().measureText(" ");
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawText(mSuffix, super.getCompoundPaddingRight(), getBaseline(), getPaint());
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingRight() {
    return super.getCompoundPaddingRight()+ mSuffixRect.width();
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I tried Iharob Al Asimi's answer and I think it's good point to start. It's working but having following issues.

- suffix not align with original text
- Not getting original text color

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I really like high quality results, it seems that on this platform it doesn't really matter for some programmers.

For me it's really important, that the look of my custom `EditText` view with a suffix is as natural as possible so I solved it in a very elegant and simple way.

Instead of doing some unreliable layout hacks or attempting to intercept the `onDraw()` method of the edit text, it would seem more natural to add a compound drawable to the right of the view and draw the text on it.

It's a simple solution, it doesn't break anything and it looks very "*native*".

From the example you linked, there is something that really helps a lot and it's the implementation of the `onMesure()` method, it makes room for the compound drawable, and that's precisely how I got the idea of using a compound drawable.

Here is the code so you can use it in future projects if the same requirement arises

```
public class SuffixEditText extends EditText {
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private String mSuffix;
    private float mSuffixWidth;
    private Drawable mSuffixDrawable;

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        Resources resources = getResources();

        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
        // Using the same foreground color could
        // be confusing.
        mTextPaint.setColor(getCurrentHintTextColor());
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

        mSuffixDrawable = new Drawable() {
            @Override
            public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
                if (mSuffix == null)
                    return;
                canvas.drawText(mSuffix, 0, getPaddingTop(), mTextPaint);
            }

            @Override
            public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
            }

            @Override
            public int getOpacity() {
                return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
            }
        };
    }

    public SuffixEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public SuffixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public SuffixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        mSuffix = suffix;
        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, mSuffixDrawable, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mSuffix != null)
            mSuffixWidth = mTextPaint.measureText(" " + mSuffix);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompoundPaddingRight() {
        return super.getCompoundPaddingRight() + (int) Math.ceil(mSuffixWidth);
    }
}
```

In my opinion, android's API is horribly designed and it makes doing something simple a very difficult task, when some other times it's incredibly stupid to do some other thing. I would prefer a consistent API like Qt's where you can do anything you want.

---

**NOTE**: There might happen to be some optimizations to this code but I am not a Java programmer, so I ignore the way things work and can't come up with more efficient code.

Also, a better implementation would take care of the other drawables in case they were present. Because setting them to `null` might override the previously set drawables anyway. And clearly, this view can't have an additional right drawable as it is implemented in this code.

Comment: Sorry, Somehow i didn't notice this question was answered. It's working but not in center with it's text. I'll add more detailed to in original question.

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna Centering is something that can be achieved if you understand my code. Read it carefully. I recall that I didn't want the text centered.